# Moen kitchen faucet loose

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

I have a moen kitchen faucet that keeps coming loose.  From below, I can tighten the nut, however it will not stay tight.  As soon as I take my hand or wrench off the nut, it starts spinning backwards.

The other issue is that who ever initially drilled the hole, did not align it properly so you can see it is partially touching and the other side is just hanging.  I did manage to cut a plate to stick in there so that it fills the gap like a shim.  However, it keeps falling out since everything comes loose.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it possible that the threads are stripped?  Nuts usually don't spin off by themselves, they can loosen if threads are stripped and just hanging on.  In that case a replacement is what will be needed.

Comment: Bot: I would think it would be clear that I am asking for potential solutions to keeping it from coming loose

Comment: crip659: I don't think so, I feel it getting tight as I spin.  I can get it very tight but as soon as I take my hand or wrench off, it spins backwards.  I think the issue is because of the alignment.  so its not flush for half of it because of the gap.  I tried putting something there to fill the gap but maybe its not a perfect fit.  Not sure how else to fix it.  I figure another faucet will have the same issue

Comment: @eng3  This is very odd, nuts don't spin off by themselves, unless there is heavy vibrations(gas engine).  They will stay in place if tight or loose unless acted upon.  Alignment of the treads are a must or they will be stripped.  It is why most people put nuts on by hand before using tools.